# How to get an Acer Aspire Revo to connect to the wireless keyboard and mouse?

Tags: keyboard, wireless-networking, mouse, acer-aspire, acer-revo

I just got a new Asus Aspire Revo, put the batteries in the wireless keyboard and mouse, but I can't get the system to recognize either. What am I doing wrong?

Note: There are next to no instructions with this product.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're at wit's end, get ready for some relief and amazement.

They actually tucked the USB dongle for the keyboard **inside the battery compartment of the mouse**!

Dig it out, plug it in, and all will be fine. Make sure to press the connect button on the back of the keyboard for a few seconds and the wireless keyboard and mouse will be recognized.